# Windows 7 can't reconnect network drives on startup

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, samba, smb

I have this annoying problem that Windows 7 won't reconnect to my network drives on startup. The shares are on an Ubuntu machine.

[image: could not reconnect]

I've tried every possible solution I've found:

- Enable password on logon to give the network interface time to boot up
- Check `Connect using different credentials`

  [image: map network drive]
- Tried both options in this screen

  [image: password]

Sorry for the long post. Can You please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ultimately worked, was setting the same credentials on server and client. Then Windows didn't have to remember anything, just login with my standard login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to the share by hostname, not IP address. In my experience, Windows never liked remembering passwords for IP addresses. Also, it's unlikely this is the cause since it looks like this is a home installation, but there are group policy settings to prevent passwords from being remembered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really thought this would work, but it didn't :( This is a home installation, but I'll check the policies to be safe